# Error al copiar archivo en C

Tags: c, linux, archivo

Estoy haciendo un pequeño sistema de temperaturas, tengo un error al querer realizar una copiar de cierta categoría de temperatura. Ya que los valores no coinciden solo el penúltimo valor es el que coincide. En el archivo copia se van juntando los valores o hacen cosas raras. ¿Como lo podría corregir mi funcion COPIATEMPERATURA?, gracias. (Uso linux)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void LEERTEMPERATURA (int,int[10],int[10],int[10],int*,int*,int*);
void COPIATEMPERATURA (int[10],int[10],int[10],int*,int*,int*);
void IMPRIMIRTEMP();
void IMPRIMIRCOPIATEMP();

int main (){

int temp,tA[10],tB[10],tC[10];
int A,B,C;

    printf("Cuantas temperaturas registraras: ");
    scanf("%d",&temp);
    temp=temp-1;
    
    LEERTEMPERATURA(temp,tA,tB,tC,&A,&B,&C);
    IMPRIMIRTEMP();
    printf("\n\nNo de temperaturas que registraste: ");
    printf("\n%d- A",A);
    printf("\n%d- B",B);
    printf("\n%d- C",C);
    
    COPIATEMPERATURA(tA,tB,tC,&A,&B,&C);
    IMPRIMIRCOPIATEMP();
    
    return 0;
}

void LEERTEMPERATURA (int temp,int temA[10],int temB[10],int temC[10],int*A,int*B,int*C){
    
FILE *fptr;
int i,num,a=0,b=0,c=0;

    fptr=fopen("temperatura.txt","wt");
    
    if(fptr==NULL)
        printf("No se pudo abrir el archivo\n");
    else{
        
        for(i=0;i<=temp;i++){
        printf("\n¿Que medidor usaras [A,B,C]=[1,2,3]?: ");
        scanf("%d",&num);

        switch(num){
            case 1:
            printf("Para el medidor A: \n");
            scanf("%ls",&temA[i]);
            fprintf(fptr,"A: %ls\n",&temA[i]);
            a++;
            break;
            
            case 2:
            printf("Para el medidor B: \n");
            scanf("%ls",&temB[i]);
            fprintf(fptr,"B: %ls\n",&temB[i]);
            b++;
            break;
            
            case 3:
            printf("Para el medidor B: \n");
            scanf("%ls",&temC[i]);
            fprintf(fptr,"C: %ls\n",&temC[i]);
            c++;
            break;
            }
        }
        *A=a;
        *B=b;
        *C=c;
    }
        fclose(fptr);

}

void IMPRIMIRTEMP(){
    
    FILE *fptr;
    fptr=fopen("temperatura.txt","rt");
    
    if(fptr==NULL)
        printf("No se pudo abrir el archivo\n");
    else{
        printf( "\nContenido del fichero:\n" );
    while (!feof(fptr))
        printf( "%c",getc(fptr) );
    fclose(fptr);
   }
}
```

**ES AQUI DONDE HACE COSAS RARAS EL CÓDIGO** (Aunque también tengo sospechas que podría ser que mi arreglo de la función leer temperatura no este funcionando bien)

```
void COPIATEMPERATURA(int tA[10],int tB[10],int tC[10],int*A,int*B,int*C){
    
    FILE *fptrcopia;
    int num,i;
    
    fptrcopia=fopen("tempcopia.txt","wt");
    
    printf("\n\nQue temperatura vas a realizar una copia [A,B,C]=[1,2,3]: ");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    
    if(fptrcopia==NULL){
        printf("No se pudo abrir el archivo\n");
    }
    else{
    switch(num){
            case 1:
            printf("\nEl medidor A ha sido copiado... \n");
            for(i=0;i<=*A;i++){
            fprintf(fptrcopia,"A: %ls\n",&tA[i]);
            }
            break;
            
            case 2:
            printf("\nEl medidor B ha sido copiado... \n");
            for(i=0;i<=*B;i++){
            fprintf(fptrcopia,"B: %ls\n",&tB[i]);
            }
            break;
            
            case 3:
            printf("\nEl medidor B ha sido copiado... \n");
            for(i=0;i<=*C;i++){
            fprintf(fptrcopia,"C: %ls\n",&tC[i]);
            }
            break;
            }
    }
    fclose(fptrcopia);
}

void IMPRIMIRCOPIATEMP(){
        
    FILE *fptrcopia;
    fptrcopia=fopen("tempcopia.txt","rt");
    
    if(fptrcopia==NULL)
        printf("No se pudo abrir el archivo\n");
    else{
        printf( "\nContenido del fichero:\n" );
    while (!feof(fptrcopia))
        printf( "%c",getc(fptrcopia) );
    fclose(fptrcopia);
   }
}
```

**Esta es la salida de mi terminal**

```
Cuantas temperaturas registraras: 5

¿Que medidor usaras [A,B,C]=[1,2,3]?: 1
Para el medidor A: 
20

¿Que medidor usaras [A,B,C]=[1,2,3]?: 1
Para el medidor A: 
10

¿Que medidor usaras [A,B,C]=[1,2,3]?: 2
Para el medidor B: 
30

¿Que medidor usaras [A,B,C]=[1,2,3]?: 3
Para el medidor B: 
40

¿Que medidor usaras [A,B,C]=[1,2,3]?: 1
Para el medidor A: 
40

Contenido del fichero:
A: 20
A: 10
B: 30
C: 40
A: 40
�

No de temperaturas que registraste: 
3- A
1- B
1- C

Que temperatura vas a realizar una copia [A,B,C]=[1,2,3]: 1

El medidor A ha sido copiado... 

Contenido del fichero:
A: 210
A: 10
A: 0
A: 
�

introducir el código aquí
```

Comment: **%s** y **%ls** son para cadenas de texto. ¿Por qué los usas con números?

Comment: Si pero el compilador me marcaba error y que debía ponerlo en ese formato, en un inicio le había puesto %d

Answer (score 0):

Como te comenté, el problema es que estás usando mal `scanf` y `printf`.

Para leer un entero debes pasar la dirección de memoria en la que se va a guardar y para escribirlo simplemente pasas el valor de la variable. Por ejemplo:

```
int numero;
scanf("%d", &numero);
printf("%d", numero);

int numeros[3];
scanf("%d", &numeros[0]);
printf("1: %d", numeros[0]);
scanf("%d", &numeros[1]);
printf("2: %d", numeros[1]);
scanf("%d", &numeros[2]);
printf("3: %d", numeros[2]);
```

Puedes ver que con esas correcciones el programa funciona como esperas [aquí](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/185My85pzQlVcGmuCQlM18vw44rM69EITcxM09DU6Gai7OgtKRYQ8kjNScnX0chPL8oJ0VRSdOaq/b/fwA).

Comment: Muchas gracias, si era ese error de poner el "&" al momento de leer. Ya funciona mi programa :D